# javascript: program get stuck

Tags: javascript, web

I'm learing javascript on *codecademy*. The following program got stuck when I submitted it. I am new to this so I can not find the bug. I downloaded *Aptana Studio* but I don't know how to debug:(. Is there any way to trace the code? Thanks in advance.

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.random() > 0.5;
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(5 * Math.random());
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying) {
    if (youHit) {
        console.log("You hit the dragon.");
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;
        if (totalDamage >= 4) {
            console.log("You've stew the dragon!");
            slaying = false;
        } else {
            youHit = Math.random() > 0.5;
        }
    } else {
        console.log("The dragon defeated you.")
    }
}
```

Comment: All debugging for `JavaScript` is done within the browser itself, press `F12` in your browser and select `console` =)

Comment: Are you asking how to debug JavaScript?

Comment: @Pavio  My purpose is to solve the bug. So you can think in that way.

Comment: Do you plan to create new question every time you have a bug? You'll definitely need to learn how to debug, but that kind of question is out of SO scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding. You need to set `slaying = false` in else section, otherwise the program will be thrown into an *infinite* loop.

```
} else {
    slaying = false; //Added here - Breaks the while() condition
    console.log("The dragon defeated you.")
}
```

Simple, when `The dragon defeated you.` slaying stops. (Pun intended)

For Debugging use Chrome's built in `Developer tools` or `Firebug` in Firefox. Both, use `F12` to access whilst in your chosen browser.

Comment: If `youHit` is false then the loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

yes. if you use Chrome you can use built-in Dev Tools or (if using Firefox) you can use FireBug extension

Answer (score 0):

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.random() > 0.5;
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(5 * Math.random());
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying) {
    if (youHit) {
        console.log("You hit the dragon.");
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;
        if (totalDamage >= 4) {
        console.log("You've stew the dragon!");
            slaying = false;
        } else {
        youHit = Math.random() > 0.5;
        }
    } else {
        //add this line
        slaying = false;    
        console.log("The dragon defeated you.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.random() > 0.5;
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(5 * Math.random());
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying) {
    if (youHit) {
        console.log("You hit the dragon.");
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;
        if (totalDamage >= 4) {
        console.log("You've stew the dragon!");
            slaying = false;
        } else {
        youHit = Math.random() > 0.5;
        }
    } else {
        console.log("The dragon defeated you.");
        slaying=false;
    }
}
```

you missed slaying false in else case. so if you don't do that its in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add false after the else statement (containing dragon defeated you). Like this

```
} else {
    console.log("The dragon defeated you.");
    slaying=false;
}
```

Otherwise, it is an infinite loop, which causes one's browser to crash. If it was JAVA or something more like that, the game would not just stop, but it is JS - you cannot have a loop without ending.